# Spring WS Async SOAP Client and JMS Listener

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-ws, spring-jms

All,

I would like to create the Async. SOAP Client using Spring WS WebServiceTemplate mechanism. Is it possible?

The detail use case is given below -

1. The Client application (in Spring) will call the ESB's @OneWay SOAP Service with few parameters which includes unique ID.
2. After receiving the SOAP request ESB will create a Queue at MQ and will post the payload.
3. The client application has to Subscribe to queue to get the response back.
4. MQ will post the message to client application.

I would appreciate any help/suggestion on this implementation.

Thanks in advance.